# Argument forwarding for emplace() makes constructor arguments const

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm trying to use `emplace()` to construct in-place a `map<K,V>` entry (using Boost).  The key object constructor arg gets forwarded through the template magic correctly, but the `V object` constructor arg becomes const, so it doesn't work.

```
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>

class A {
  public:
    /**/     A( int n ) { }
    friend bool operator<( const A &a1, const A &a2 ) { return false; }
} ;

class B {
  public:
    /**/     B( const char *str ) { }
} ;

class C {
  public:
    /**/     C( B &b ) { }
} ;

int
main( int, char ** )
{
    boost::container::map<A,B>   m1;
    boost::container::map<A,C>   m2;
    B                            b( "Foo" );
    C                            c( b ); // <--- this works OK.

    m1.emplace( 1, "Hello" );
    m2.emplace( 2, b ); // <----- this fails!
}
```

The Error is:

```
Error: /usr/local/include/boost/container/detail/pair.hpp:128:38: error: no matching function for call to C::C(const B&), second(::boost::forward<V>(v))
```

Something about the emplace argument-forwarding turns `b` into `const b` in the last line.  I know there must be a `boost::bla_bla_bla` that I can apply to make it work, but I haven't been able to find it.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Compiler is g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, Boost version 1.60.0

Comment: It turns out, I needed an extra command-line argument to get this version of g++ to do C++-11.  Once added, everything works!  (g++ -std=c++11 foo.cc)

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you compile this using `-std=c++11` (or later), this will work. Why this is the case took a bit of digging - I'm using a slightly older version of boost (1.56), but I doubt this has changed much between the two releases.

Using `emplace` generally requires perfect forwarding. This means all of the arguments are forwarded as via `std::forward<Args>(args)...`. Underneath, this relies on reference collapsing and move semantics - this is all C++11 territory, and has no analog in C++03.

If we dig into the boost code for `pair` (where it's actually generating the error), then this is the constructor it's attempting to call:

```
template<class U, class V>
pair(BOOST_FWD_REF(U) u, BOOST_FWD_REF(V) v)
   : first(::boost::forward<U>(u))
   , second(::boost::forward<V>(v))
{}
```

Unfortunately, `BOOST_FWD_REF` (which is in `move/core.hpp`) is one of the following:

```
#define BOOST_FWD_REF(TYPE)\
   const TYPE & \
//

#define BOOST_FWD_REF(TYPE)\
    const TYPE & \
//
```

When your compiler does not recognise rvalue references, this will then become `const TYPE&`.

There's a bit of discussion on this [on the boost archives list](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2012/01/189576.php).

The easiest solution is to simply compile with `std=c++11`.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I had figured out the c++-11 part, and ran across rvalue references in my reading, but didn't understand enough of the surrounding information to put it all together into a comprehensive answer (as you've done).